# Crazy rectangles, semi-circles, and circles!

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, triangles, rectangles

> [image]
>
> Problem is to find the ratio of the area of the circle to that of the semi-circle.

Note that points $F$ and $E$ weren't given in the original diagram, and that the circle at the top-right is touching the semi-circle as well as the two sides of the rectangle.

I don't have any idea on where to start. I have seen [these things](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.06/s/lori1.html), but this question is completely different. If even I could compute the diagonal $B$ to center of semi-circle, there would be a very tiny gap at the top-right.

Any help/hints on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be the radius of the semicircle, and $r$ the radius of the little circle. Let $O$ be the centre of the semicircle. Then $OB=R\sqrt{2}$ and $EB=r\sqrt{2}$. It follows that
$$R\sqrt{2}=R+r+r\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: If you're confused OP, treat the little circle as if it's in a square and you know the diagonal.

Comment: Well, I understood how the equation formed @qwr I am actually wondering how do I solve the equation. All I can see is $R(\sqrt{2}-1)=r(\sqrt{2} + 1)$. I need help in solving this please :)

Comment: @GaurangTandon Simple, find the ratio of $r/R$ and you can apply the circle area formula

Comment: @qwr I really feel I need some sleep :P It's 1 AM here in India. My brain ain't working :D

Comment: You are almost there. Divide both sides by $R(\sqrt{2}+1)$. We get $R\frac{r}{R}=\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1}$. You can then if you wish multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{2}-1$, getting $\frac{r}{R}=(\sqrt{2}-1)^2=3-2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I still need help, please :) I found $\pi r^2:\pi R^2/2$ = $2r^2/R^2$. But, then, what do I do further ? Do I square $3-2\sqrt{2}$ and multiply it by $2$ ??

Comment: Exactly. It is clear that you know how to solve the problem.